# How to add IOKit.framework to xcode 6.2

Tags: xcode, iokit

I don't see IOKit.framework when I try to add framework from Build phases setting. I can see the framework being present at following locations though:

Macintosh HD ▸ Applications ▸ Xcode ▸ Contents ▸ Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ iPhoneOS.platform ▸ Developer ▸ SDKs ▸ iPhoneOS.sdk ▸ System ▸ Library ▸ Frameworks

Macintosh HD ▸ Applications ▸ Xcode ▸ Contents ▸ Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ iPhoneOS.platform ▸ Developer ▸ SDKs ▸ iPhoneOS8.2.sdk ▸ System ▸ Library ▸ Frameworks

I have seen IOKit.framework added in latest KIF projects. Not sure how to do that. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Though Apple doesn't allow you to choose it from build phases setting, you can just drag and drop IOKit.framework in build phases section.

Comment: I'm getting File Not Found when doing `#import <IOKit/IOKit>`. I dragged the iOKit.framework into the Link Binary with Libraries. What is left to do?